# Truncated incorrect datetime value - Textfield with Timezone

Tags: mysql

**Mysql 5.7**

I have two tables - one with a Date+Time+Timezone in a TEXT field. The other has a Datetime field.

I know want to migrate the values from table a (varchar) to table b (datetime). I can select both values and they "look" the same - but Mysql will not allow an insert/update.

```
CREATE TABLE a (date_text_with_tz TEXT);
CREATE TABLE b (date_datetime DATETIME);

INSERT INTO b SELECT '2022-03-22 11:11:11';
INSERT INTO a SELECT '2022-03-22T11:11:11+01:00';

-- This shows pretty much the same values
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date_text_with_tz, '%Y-%m-%d %T'), b.date_datetime FROM a
CROSS JOIN
b;
```

And this

```
INSERT INTO b SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(a.date_text_with_tz, '%Y-%m-%d %T')) FROM a
```

returns

> Query Error: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect
> datetime value: '2022-03-22T11:11:11+01:00'

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQPVimJZCvc574a1fJJ5Wf/0

How can I migrate the values from the varchar field to the datetime field? The timezone can be ommited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't bother about the timezone offset, this should work  (if all your TS strings have `+01:00` which I have supposed)

```
INSERT INTO b SELECT ( STR_TO_DATE(a.date_text_with_tz, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s+01:00')) FROM a
```

Comment: So what I missed was - that I have to match "the whole" Date in the `STR_TO_DATE` function?

Comment: MySQL doesn't manage  [iso-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. So you basically have to hardcode the `T` and `+01:00` parts so it can properly understand the whole string, parse only the relevant date/time parts: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`, and convert to datetime